# WFS-T operations using GeoJSON in OpenLayers

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs-t

This project https://jsfiddle.net/h7mk0jpt/ performs some tasks such as edit, delete, insert shapes using OpenLayers but while doing these operations, it uses GML object. I couldn't perform these task using GML, even couldn't populate vector source. To fetch vectors via GeoServer, I have used WFS request and it works and populated by using GeoJSON.  The example in the link which use GML to populate vector source and inserts, delete and edit process.

How can I do these tasks using GeoJSON via WFS-T?

I want to create a web app using OpenLayers which will do same process.

Firstly, it will map by vector source using OpenLayers,  the data of vector source will be fetched via GeoServer. when some draw is done which will be added related geoserver source.

I have tried to work same code script by changing workspace and layer but haven't got any result. If you run this code script, I will be okay such as other solutions.

This is the first script which is changed by using my workspace and layer.

```
var formatWFS = new ol.format.WFS();

var formatGML = new ol.format.GML({
    featureNS: 'http://myIp/geoserver/myWorkSpace',
    featureType: 'myLayerNameonGeoserver',
    srsName: 'EPSG:3857'
});

var xs = new XMLSerializer();

var sourceWFS = new ol.source.Vector({
    loader: function (extent) {
        $.ajax('http://10.3.2.5:8081/geoserver/BaskentGaz/ows', {
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                service: 'WFS',
                version: '1.1.0',
                request: 'GetFeature',
                typename: 'myLayerNameOnGeoserver',
                srsname: 'EPSG:5255', //cause of my layer epsg is 5255
                bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:5255'
            }
        }).done(function (response) {
            sourceWFS.addFeatures(formatWFS.readFeatures(response));
        });
    },
    //strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ()),
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
    projection: 'EPSG:5255'
});

var layerWFS = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: sourceWFS
});

var interaction;

var interactionSelectPointerMove = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove
});

var interactionSelect = new ol.interaction.Select({
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#FF2828'
        })
    })
});

var interactionSnap = new ol.interaction.Snap({
    source: layerWFS.getSource()
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    controls: [],
    interactions: [
        interactionSelectPointerMove,
        new ol.interaction.MouseWheelZoom(),
        new ol.interaction.DragPan()
    ],
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM({
                url: 'https://cartodb-basemaps-{a-d}.global.ssl.fastly.net/dark_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                opaque: false,
                attributions: []
            })
        }),
        layerWFS
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-1.7, 53.2]),
        zoom: 6
    })
});

//wfs-t
var dirty = {};
var transactWFS = function (mode, f) {
    var node;
    switch (mode) {
        case 'insert':
            node = formatWFS.writeTransaction([f], null, null, formatGML);
            break;
        case 'update':
            node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, [f], null, formatGML);
            break;
        case 'delete':
            node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, null, [f], formatGML);
            break;
    }
    var payload = xs.serializeToString(node);
    $.ajax('https://gsx.geolytix.net/geoserver/geolytix_wfs/ows', {
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'xml',
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'text/xml',
        data: payload
    }).done(function() {
        sourceWFS.clear();
    });
};

$('button').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('btn-active');
    $(this).addClass('btn-active');
    map.removeInteraction(interaction);
    interactionSelect.getFeatures().clear();
    map.removeInteraction(interactionSelect);

    switch ($(this).attr('id')) {

        case 'btnEdit':
            map.addInteraction(interactionSelect);
            interaction = new ol.interaction.Modify({
                features: interactionSelect.getFeatures()
            });
            map.addInteraction(interaction);
            map.addInteraction(interactionSnap);
            dirty = {};
            interactionSelect.getFeatures().on('add', function (e) {
                e.element.on('change', function (e) {
                    dirty[e.target.getId()] = true;
                });
            });
            interactionSelect.getFeatures().on('remove', function (e) {
                var f = e.element;
                if (dirty[f.getId()]) {
                    delete dirty[f.getId()];
                    var featureProperties = f.getProperties();
                    delete featureProperties.boundedBy;
                    var clone = new ol.Feature(featureProperties);
                    clone.setId(f.getId());
                    transactWFS('update', clone);
                }
            });
            break;

        case 'btnPoint':
            interaction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                type: 'Point',
                source: layerWFS.getSource()
            });
            map.addInteraction(interaction);
            interaction.on('drawend', function (e) {
                transactWFS('insert', e.feature);
            });
            break;

        case 'btnLine':
            interaction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                type: 'LineString',
                source: layerWFS.getSource()
            });
            map.addInteraction(interaction);
            interaction.on('drawend', function (e) {
                transactWFS('insert', e.feature);
            });
            break;

        case 'btnArea':
            interaction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                type: 'Polygon',
                source: layerWFS.getSource()
            });
            interaction.on('drawend', function (e) {
                transactWFS('insert', e.feature);
            });
            map.addInteraction(interaction);
            break;

        case 'btnDelete':
            interaction = new ol.interaction.Select();
            interaction.getFeatures().on('add', function (e) {
                transactWFS('delete', e.target.item(0));
                interactionSelectPointerMove.getFeatures().clear();
                interaction.getFeatures().clear();
            });
            map.addInteraction(interaction);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
});
```

when above script is run, ol.source.OSM layer is displayed. I suggest, my vector doesn't come.

In the below script, I have populated inside vector source using GeoJSON. But I don't know how to insert GeoJSON object to GeoServer layer when I finish a drawing, only I need to insert, delete and modify to GeoServer layer using WFS-T OpenLayers.

```
 var source = new ol.source.Vector({
        url: 'myIp/geoserver/myWorkSpace/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=myWorkSpace:myLayerNameOnGeoServer&outputFormat=application%2Fjson',
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()

    });
    var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: source
    });


    // if this is just a coverage or a group of them, disable a few items,
    // and default to jpeg format

    var bounds = [437762.766104487, 4376882.69760637,
                  522118.932880649, 4461344.83731443];  

    var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
        code: 'EPSG:5255',
        units: 'm',
        axisOrientation: 'neu'
    });

    var map = new ol.Map({

        target: 'map',
        layers: [

          vector
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
            projection: projection
        })
    });

    map.getView().on('change:resolution', function (evt) {
        var resolution = evt.target.get('resolution');
        var units = map.getView().getProjection().getUnits();
        var dpi = 25.4 / 0.28;
        var mpu = ol.proj.METERS_PER_UNIT[units];
        var scale = resolution * mpu * 39.37 * dpi;
        if (scale >= 9500 && scale <= 950000) {
            scale = Math.round(scale / 1000) + "K";
        } else if (scale >= 950000) {
            scale = Math.round(scale / 1000000) + "M";
        } else {
            scale = Math.round(scale);
        }

    });
    map.getView().fit(bounds, map.getSize());
```